# How do I code in java arguments into my main/constructors?

Tags: java, executable

I have an executable

So the two constructors look like this:

```
public A()
{
//code
}
```

and

```
public A(String foo)
{
//more code here
}
```

The main looks like this:

```
A foo = new A();
```

Which of course, executes only the first constructor.

In B.jar, I'm calling it up like this:

```
rt.exec("java -jar pathToA.jar");
```

In another executable jar, called "B.jar", I would like to have the capability to execute A.jar using either constructor. How should I implement this? Should I get rid of the `main` method in my A.jar?

Comment: Have another main class in your *A.jar* that uses `A foo = new A(args[0]);` inside the `public static void main` and execute it when you launc the command.

Comment: You should invoke the classes in `A.jar` directly as Java code, not launch a second process.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Ah! That makes much more sense. Thank you.

Comment: The only reason not to do that is if you are a launcher process, and you don't want a child process to get killed etc. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass all args, I'd suggest keeping a constructor as:

```
A(String []args) {
}
```

and calling:

```
public static void main(String []args) {
 new A(args);
}
```

in the main function in the jar.

Comment: Should I get rid of my `A(String foo)`, then?

Comment: Not a good idea for maintainability, but can be good for a quick proof of concept code (although that's how things start always).

Answer (score 0):

You can also chain the two constructors. See Constructor Chaining:
http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-constructors

```
public A()
{
  this("default str", 0);
}

public A(String foo, int bar)
{
  // more code here
}
```

(I think that's better than String[] args, because you can easily mix up the order of the args, and also that way you could only handle Strings. (To handle different types you could use Object[] args, but that's even less maintainable since it's not even type safe.) And you want to keep the number of arguments under control.)

Note, that Usually someone want's to chain the other way, so the parameterized constructor would call the one with less parameters.

```
public A()
{
  // more code here
}

public A(String foo)
{
  this.setFoo(foo);
  // more code here
}

public A(String foo, int bar)
{
  this(foo);
  this.setBar(bar);
}

public A(String foo, int bar, float extra)
{
  this(foo, bar);
  this.setExtra(extra);
}
```